# Modal Component doesn't update even though data is sourced from useContext, where the Array is updated by the useReducer Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the title says it all - but I will try to give a more eloquent description of the problem. I am trying to build a food order App for practice (I am a beginner).
This App has a Cart, where you can put in items, which you can then order - this cart has a display in the nav-bar on how many items you currently have in your cart, because a big part of the pages functionality, so my thought pattern, depends on the state of the cart (being able to order and proceed to payment, delete items, display item amount in navbar) I thought it would be a good idea to put this in a context component. In this context component I implemented the useReducer hook, to update itemCount, cartState, and the modalState (show / don't show). Adding items works fine, UI updates the corresponding number of items in the cart, and when opening the cart-modal the correct items are displayed. However when I click on an item to delete it, the delete operation gets performed correctly (array splice), but the modal doesn't get updated and I can't figure why.
A theory which I have, is that it may be because I have put more then one component in the modal component in order to work with react portals (and I haven't yet completely understood how react portals work) and therefore have messed something up there - or that I got some kind of logical error, that I am not able to resolve myself.

I am thankful for any input, if you have advice on how to better structure my code or architect the app, let me know - I am eager to learn from you!

Modal Component

```
export default function Modal() {
  
  const cartC = useContext(cContext)
  

  const Backdrop = () => {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={cartC.onShowCart}
        className="w-full h-full bg-gray-800 fixed bg-opacity-75"
      ></div>
    );
  };
  const Modal = () => {    
    return (
      <div className="bg-slate-300 w-1/3 h-auto flex absolute left-1/3 top-1/3 flex-col rounded">
        <h1 className="self-center p-2 text-2xl font-bolder">Your Cart</h1>
        <div>
          {console.log(cartC.cartItems)}
          {cartC.cartItems.map((ci, index) => {
            return (
              <ModalCard
                id={index}
                key={index}
                itemName={ci.dishName}
              ></ModalCard>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="rounded bg-red-400 p-1 m-1 hover:scale-105 hover:bg-red-500 duration-300">
          <button onClick={cartC.onShowCart}>
            <div>Order and Procced to Payment</div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {reactDom.createPortal(
        <Backdrop></Backdrop>,
        document.getElementById("overlay-root")
      )}
      {reactDom.createPortal(
        <Modal></Modal>,
        document.getElementById("modal-root")
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

App Component

```
import { Fragment, useContext } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Nav/Navbar";
import alpen from "./alpen.jpg";
import Description from "./Ui/Description";
import Menu from "./Ui/Menu";
import Modal from "./Ui/Modal";
import { cContext } from "./store/CartContext";


function App() {
  const cCart = useContext(cContext);
  const showCart = cCart.showCart;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="bg-gray-900 h-screen">
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        {showCart ? <Modal></Modal> : null}
        <img className="object-cover h-1/3 w-full bg-fixed z-0" src={alpen} alt="" />
        <div className="flex flex-col">
        <Description></Description>
        <Menu></Menu>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CartContext

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { dishData } from "../data";

const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CART_COUNT":
      console.log(action.value);
      return {
        count: action.value,
        items: state.items,
        cartState: false,
      };
    case "CART_ITEMS":
      console.log(action.value);
      return {
        count: state.count,
        items: action.value,
        cartState: false,
      };
    case "DELETE_ITEM":
      console.log(action.value);
      return {
        count: state.count,
        items: action.value,
        cartState: false,
      };
    case "CART_STATE":
      console.log(action.value);
      return {
        count: state.count,
        items: state.items,
        cartState: action.value,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const cContext = createContext({
  cartItems: [],
  cartItemsCount: 0,
  onAdd: (id, amount) => {},
  onDelete: (id) => {},
  showCart: false,
  onShowCart: () => {},
});
var cartArray = [];
var cartCount = 0;

export default function Context(props) {
  const [cartState, dispatchCartReducer] = useReducer(cartReducer, {
    count: 0,
    state: false,
    items: [],
  });

  const addCartHandler = (id, amount) => {
    if (amount > 0 && id >= 0) {
      for (let x = 0; x < amount; x++) {
        cartArray.push(dishData[id]);
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
    cartCount = cartArray.length;
    dispatchCartReducer({ type: "CART_COUNT", value: cartCount });
    dispatchCartReducer({ type: "CART_ITEMS", value: cartArray });
  };
  const deleteCartHandler = (id) => {
    const stackArray = cartState.items;
    stackArray.splice(id, 1);
    console.log(stackArray);
    dispatchCartReducer({ type: "DELETE_ITEM", value: stackArray });
  };

  const showCartHandler = () => {
    if (!cartState.cartState) {
      dispatchCartReducer({ type: "CART_STATE", value: true });
    } else if (cartState.cartState) {
      dispatchCartReducer({ type: "CART_STATE", value: false });
    }
  };
  return (
    <cContext.Provider
      value={{
        cartItems: cartState.items,
        cartItemsCount: cartState.count,
        onAdd: addCartHandler,
        showCart: cartState.cartState,
        onShowCart: showCartHandler,
        onDelete: deleteCartHandler,
      }}
    >
      {console.log(cartState)}
      {props.children}
    </cContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Modal Card Component

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { cContext } from "../store/CartContext";

export default function ModalCard(props) {
  const cartContext = useContext(cContext);
  function deleteItem() {
    const id = props.id;
    cartContext.onDelete(id);
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={deleteItem} className="flex flex-row justify-center">
      <div className="bg-gray-100 w-10/12 m-1 rounded p-1 flex justify-between">
        <p>{props.itemName}</p>
        <p>{props.itemCount}</p>
        <p>X</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think that in the `deleteCartHandler` function you should update the cart count and the cart items exactly as you do in the `addCartHandler` (besides calling your delete function)

Comment: Managing both the cart items and the number of cart items as two different states is asking for trouble and will introduce human error. Manage only items as state, where the number of items is just the length of this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Rotems and Marius Florescu's recommendation I fixed it now, by refactoring the useState Hooks into one useReducer in the CartContext Component, now the UI rerenders correctly - thank you for your help.

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { dishData } from "../data";

const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CART_COUNT":
      console.log(action.value);
      return {
        count: action.value,
        items: state.items,
        cartState: false,
      };
    case "CART_ITEMS":
      console.log(action.value);
      return {
        count: state.count,
        items: action.value,
        cartState: false,
      };
    case "DELETE_ITEM":
      console.log(action.value);
      return {
        count: action.value.length,
        items: action.value,
        cartState: state.cartState,
      };
    case "CART_STATE":
      return {
        count: state.count,
        items: state.items,
        cartState: !state.cartState,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const cContext = createContext({
  cartItems: [],
  cartItemsCount: 0,
  cartTotal: 0,
  onAdd: (id, amount) => {},
  onDelete: (id) => {},
  showCart: false,
  onShowCart: () => {},
});
var cartArray = [];
var cartCount = 0;

export default function Context(props) {
  const [cartState, dispatchCartReducer] = useReducer(cartReducer, {
    count: 0,
    state: false,
    items: [],
  });

  const addCartHandler = (id, amount) => {
    if (amount > 0 && id >= 0) {
      for (let x = 0; x < amount; x++) {
        cartArray.push(dishData[id]);
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
    cartCount = cartArray.length;
    dispatchCartReducer({ type: "CART_COUNT", value: cartCount });
    dispatchCartReducer({ type: "CART_ITEMS", value: cartArray });
  };
  const deleteCartHandler = (id) => {
    const stackArray = cartState.items;
    stackArray.splice(id, 1);
    dispatchCartReducer({ type: "DELETE_ITEM", value: stackArray });
  };

  const showCartHandler = () => {
    dispatchCartReducer({ type: "CART_STATE" });
  };

  let totalCartPrice = 0;
  for (let x = 0; x < cartState.items.length; x++) {
    console.log(cartState.items[x].dishPrice);
    totalCartPrice += cartState.items[x].dishPrice;
  }
  totalCartPrice = Math.round(totalCartPrice);
  console.log(totalCartPrice);
  return (
    <cContext.Provider
      value={{
        cartItems: cartState.items,
        cartItemsCount: cartState.count,
        cartTotal: totalCartPrice,
        onAdd: addCartHandler,
        showCart: cartState.cartState,
        onShowCart: showCartHandler,
        onDelete: deleteCartHandler,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </cContext.Provider>
  );
}
```